# Regex expression to extract Excel cell reference

Tags: python-3.x, excel, regex

Looking for a regex which will extract Excel cell range reference and give me a tuple of column and rows. For example:

```
Input: A5:CCC8
Output: (A, 5), (CCC, 8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.findall`:

```py
inp =  "A5:CCC8"
cells = re.findall(r'[A-Z]+[0-9]+(?=:)|(?<=:)[A-Z]+[0-9]+', inp)
cells = [re.findall(r'([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)', x)[0] for x in cells]
print(cells)  # [('A', '5'), ('CCC', '8')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from re import compile

pattern = compile("(\w+)(\d+):(\w+)(\d+)")


def extract_cell(cell: str):
    result = pattern.findall(cell)[0]
    result = [result[x:x+2] for x in range(0, len(result), 2)]
    return result


print(extract_cell("A5:CCC8"))
```

Gives the result
`[('A', '5'), ('CCC', '8')]`, which you can manipulate to print out and more.
to achieve the output you stated you need:

`print(" ".join(map(str, extract_cell("A5:CCC8"))).replace("'", ""))`

Comment: Thanks but I believe this does not cater to all cases - will have to tweak the regex: print(extract_cell("A5:CCC18")) gives ==> [('A', '5'), ('CCC1', '8')] instead of [('A', '5'), ('CCC', '18')]